# Issue loading css to button autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

So I've been working with the autodesk viewer and managed to include it in a vue.js project.

I'm working with the V6 viewer and created my project with the `Vue cli-3` and have been working on the tutorials.

My issue for now is that the css classes added to a viewer button are not loaded.

Here is what I mean:

```
ToolbarExtension.prototype.createUI = function() {

 var viewer = this.viewer;

 // Button 1
 var button1 = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('my-view-front-button');
 button1.onClick = function(e) {
   viewer.setViewCube('front');
 };
 button1.addClass('my-view-front-button');
 button1.setToolTip('View front');

 // Button 2
 var button2 = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('my-view-back-button');
 button2.onClick = function(e) {
   viewer.setViewCube('back');
 };
 button2.addClass('my-view-back-button');
 button2.setToolTip('View Back');

 // SubToolbar
 this.subToolbar = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('my-custom-view-toolbar');
 this.subToolbar.addControl(button1);
 this.subToolbar.addControl(button2);

 viewer.toolbar.addControl(this.subToolbar);
 };
```

This code is used so i can create a toolbar with two buttons.

Basicly these lines add a css class to the buttons.

```
 button1.addClass('my-view-front-button');
 button2.addClass('my-view-back-button');
```

and here is my result

[image]

As you can see my buttons are blank and they're supposed to be red and blue.

```
.my-view-front-button {
  background: red;
}
.my-view-back-button {
  background: blue;
}
```

I tried to work with an other blank vue project (same with cli-3 and it does work.)

I'd like to find a solution about this issue. I've met a lot problems with this lib and not a lot of solutions.

Thank you for you help.

I'll do my best to answer your questions if something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked up my code and found out the solution to my problem.

I was using the viewer as an a child component, the thing is, i had to change the scoped property from the `<style lang="scss" scoped></style>` directive.

Removing the `scoped` property fixed the buttons, they now look like the tutorial.

Sorry for the inconvenience, hope this post would help someone else.